# How can I get a callback after a caller has been "enqueued"?

Tags: twilio

I want to run some code that takes a few seconds to complete (lookup the appropriate agents and call them). If I do it inline, the queueing of the call is delayed by a few seconds and the caller hears silence.

The "action" callback only triggers after the caller leaves the queue, and if I do it in the "waitUrl" callback, the call music is delayed.

Is there an elegant solution for this? Like some way to run the code async, or do it in a callback that won't affect the caller experience?

I guess I could use a 3rd party service (like Zapier, e.g. incoming webhook that calls a Twilio function from an outgoing webhook) to defer the long-running code, but I'd prefer to keep everything on the Twilio platform.

Comment: Are you not able to do this work asynchronously within your own application? Like, set up a job and have a worker outside of the web process deal with it?

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to do it on Twilio rather: I want everything to be together in one place, and I want to keep the latency as low as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you've noted, there are several times that Twilio requests your application and gives you opportunities to perform these actions. But in the context of a voice call, these webhooks are synchronous.

Asynchronous webhooks come in the form of the [`statusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#statuscallback), but these callbacks only occur for major events in the lifecycle of the call such as queued (this is for when calls are initiated, not when they are enqueued), ringing, in-progress, completed, busy, failed or no-answer.

For asynchronous actions you want to take in response to synchronous webhooks, you will need to setup an asynchronous call or pass the long running action off to a job to be processed outside of the synchronous call flow. There isn't anything inherent in Twilio to do this for you.